# Having problems compiling this code for NRF24l01 on stm8s103f3p6

Tags: library, nrf24l01+, compile

It said it has mutiple libraries were found for "nRF24L01.h"
but i check the Ardurino libraries I can only found one.
And it work fine if I compile it to Arduino uno.

```
//Include Libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

//create an RF24 object
RF24 radio(8,9 );  // CE, CSN

//address through which two modules communicate.
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  while (!Serial);
    Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();

  //set the address
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);

  //Set module as receiver
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (radio.available())
  {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));

    Serial.println(text);


  }

}
```

Here is the error message

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 8.1), Board: "STM8S103F3 Breakout Board"

Multiple libraries were found for "nRF24L01.h"
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
 Used: 
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\tools\sdcc\build.10738/bin/sdcc sketch\receiver.ino.cpp 

nul re12 -c -Ddouble=float -DUSE_STDINT -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -E -MC -mstm8 -DSTM8S103 -DF_CPU=16000000L 
-DARDUINO=10810 -DARDUINO_STM8S_BLUE -DARDUINO_ARCH_STM8 
-IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0\cores\sduino 
-IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0\variants\standard 
-IC:\Users\UserName\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24 
-IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0/STM8S_StdPeriph_Driver/inc 
-IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\tools\sdcc\build.10738/include
Mark re12:C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\tools\sdcc\build.10738/bin/sdcc -c -Ddouble=float -DUSE_STDINT -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -E -MC -mstm8 -DSTM8S103 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10810 -DARDUINO_STM8S_BLUE -DARDUINO_ARCH_STM8 -IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0\cores\sduino -IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0\variants\standard -IC:\Users\UserName\Documents\Arduino\libraries\RF24 -IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\hardware\stm8\0.4.0/STM8S_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -IC:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\sduino\tools\sdcc\build.10738/include sketch\receiver.ino.cpp -o nul
cpp gefunden
In file included from C:/Users/UserName/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RF24/RF24.h:18,
                 from C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\mad\receiver\receiver.ino:4:

C:/Users/UserName/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RF24/RF24_config.h:143:30: 
fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board STM8S103F3 Breakout Board.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: High likely this library is for Arduino only, not for your MCU

Comment: The `sduino` core is lacking any form of PROGMEM compatibility layer. Contact the maintainers of it.

Comment: the error is `fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory`. ignore the 'multiple libraries' warning